# The Easiest Way To Parse/Read Json

Tags: android, json, parsing, android-json

I was searching for a Way to Parse/Read `JSON` data *Easily*. Wile Searching I discovered [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html) and thought of sharing it.

### Suppose following Json Data:

```
[
   {
     "id": 912345678901,
     "text": "How do I read JSON on Android?",
     "geo": null,
     "user": {
       "name": "android_newb",
       "followers_count": 41

   },
   {
     "id": 912345678902,
     "text": "@android_newb just use android.util.JsonReader!",
     "geo": [50.454722, -104.606667],
     "user": {
       "name": "jesse",
       "followers_count": 2
     }
   }
 ]}
```

see the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By far the easierst way would be to use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) to parse Json data to Java objects.

[This site](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) even lets you automatically create Java classes from an example JSON input (some adjustments to the classes might be necessary).

No need to do this on your own, use tools ;)

Comment: +1 That's what I mentioned. Either use Jackson or GSON. Read more about JSON Parsing libraries and benchmarks http://www.technotalkative.com/lazy-productive-android-developer-3/

Comment: @SyedAliNaqi Because it produces a lot of boilerplate code and is error prone.

Answer (score 1):

[Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) is the best library for converting JSON to object and object to JSON